# Powershell command to check for admin rights is always giving me false when i RDP into it and true when i use WinRM

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, winrm

I am trying to check my remote windows server 2012 R2 machines for admin rights to the current user via Ansible scripts. I found the following command to check for admin rights on the internet:

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
```

Now a few questions regarding this:

1) This command is giving 'false' as output when i RDP into any system with the admin account. But the same command return 'true' when i run it via Ansible (Ansible uses winRM to fire commands from a central server).

2) Is there a better command (CMD or powershell) to check if the current user has admin rights ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command always returns `true` for me when running in an RDP session as an elevated admin. Make sure to **run** your PowerShell **as admininistrator**

When using winRM or Enter-PsSession you are automatically elevated.